# Add incrementing variable in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

Assuming that I have the following RDD:

```
test1 = (('trial1',[1,2]),('trial2',[3,4]))
test1RDD = sc.parallelize(test1)
```

How can I create the following rdd:

```
((1,'trial1',[1,2]),(2,'trial2',[3,4]))
```

I tried with accumulators but it doesnt work as accumulators cannot be accessed in tasks:

```
def increm(keyvalue):
    global acc
    acc +=1
    return (acc.value,keyvalue[0],keyvalue[1])


acc = sc.accumulator(0)
test1RDD.map(lambda x: increm(x)).collect()
```

Any idea how can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [zipWithIndex](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD)

> zipWithIndex()
>
> Zips this RDD with its element indices.
>
> The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the
>   ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the
>   first partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition
>   receives the largest index.
>
> This method needs to trigger a spark job when this RDD contains more
>   than one partitions.

```
  >>> sc.parallelize(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 3).zipWithIndex().collect()
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)]
```

and use `map` to transform the RDD to have the index in front of the new RDD

**This is untested as I dont have any environment:**

```
test1 = (('trial1',[1,2]),('trial2',[3,4]))
test1RDD = sc.parallelize(test1)
test1RDD.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0]))
```